# JS scope: call parent function using namespace

Tags: javascript, namespaces, scope

How do I call a parent namespace function from within a function?

```
var myNamespace = {
    funcOne : function () {
      //do something
    },

    funcTwo : function () {
       setTimeout ( function () { 
          myNamespace.funcOne(); //how do I call funcOne?
       }, 2000);
    }
}
```

Comment: What's your actual problem?  What you're doing already should work.

Answer (score 0):

The usual way would be to use the `this` keyword inside the literal

```
var myNamespace = {
    funcOne : function () {
      //do something
    },
    funcTwo : function () {
       var self = this;
       setTimeout ( function () { 
          self.funcOne();
       }, 2000);
    }
}
```

But what you're doing should work just fine as well -> [**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/Z6kqw/)

Comment: Thanks, but it's showing `Object [object global] has no method 'setDialog'`

Comment: @M.Bennett - It's a literal, not a function, `new` doesn't really make sense ?

Comment: @Growler - There is no `setDialog` in the posted code ?